# Installing x86_64 ruby using rvm under docker in emulation

Tags: ruby, docker, rvm

I’m building a Docker image that uses ruby which I install using `rvm`. If I build under Apple Silicon using `docker buildx build --platform linux/amd64,linux/arm64 …` and in my build script I do `rvm install 2.7`, it build and installs the ARM64 version, even in the amd64 image:

```
$ uname -a
Linux 628f228dda6f 4.14.22 #1 SMP Thu Oct 27 08:01:25 UTC 2022 Build-38 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ file /home/foo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.8/bin/ruby
/home/foo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.8/bin/ruby: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, BuildID[sha1]=e3ea67d64604f36deef9f6eb95cc99078337d287, with debug_info, not stripped
```

This image obviously cannot run ruby on amd64 hardware.

How do I tell `rvm` to install the amd64 version of Ruby? I tried `ARCHFLAGS="$(uname -m)" rvm install 2.7` but it had no effect, and setting `rvm install 2.7 --arch x86_64` results in compile errors from gcc.

Comment: Can you show the `Dockerfile` you're working with here? Are you sure the `buildx` arguments are being propagated properly?

Comment: It’s a large, convoluted build I’m trying to reduce to a small set. Right now, I can build an image with rvm, but it fails in emulation using `buildx` but succeeds (and works correctly) if I build it with `docker build`. In the meantime, the source for what I’m really trying to build is here: https://gitlab.com/koehn-docker/diaspora

Comment: You can download the offending image at `koehn/diaspora`.

Comment: It's not clear where you're running these commands, or what you're building.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I had a `FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM` in my `Dockerfile`, which forced a single build of that stage using my Mac’s (ARM64) architecture. Subsequent build stages were multi-platform and worked correctly, but copied the ARM Ruby code.